# Changing the default namespace from xs: to xs1: in xsd is not working

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd

I need to define a custom namespace for my XSD say xs1. So, I have created a XSD as below by changing the default namespace from xs to xs1.

```
<xs1:schema  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
      xmlns:xs1="http://schemas/Generic/">
  <xs1:element name="listOfDocumentFolders">
     enter code here`.....
  </xs1>
```

The above xsd is not working and In visual studio xml schema explorer, it is showing as

> Not found or invalid.. [image: visual studio error]

Can anyone please guide me how to use a custom namespace otherthan xs in XSD..

Answer (score 0):

Some important points regarding XML namespaces in XSD that you may be misunderstanding:

- `xs:` and `xs1:` are namespace *prefixes*, not *namespaces*. 
  Namespace prefixes themselves are insignificant; it is only through
  the namespace (eg `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`) to which
  they're bound that they derive meaning.
- The namespace that defines the elements and attributes of XSD itself
  is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` and cannot be changed and still
  refer to standard XSD.  You can, however, change the namespace prefix
  to anything you'd like; `xs` and `xsd` are most common.
- Typically, it's the namespace of the XML for which a given XSD
  governs that one wishes to change.  For this, use `targetNamespace`.